Removing attribution because someone was charged but not convicted with a crime?
When someone is charged with a crime, they don't - as I understand it - lose their rights under the Creative Commons license. I know one such user has had his right of attribution stripped. I find this action to be an overreach on Stack Exchange's part. He contributed to the network's success. His previous name on the network was "Luigi Mangione".
Given that the company removed the name from this account, does Stack Exchange claim that they can strip attribution at any time when a person is charged, and not even convicted, of a crime?

You can see the old profile here.

I can confirm SE, Inc. were the ones to clear his name. A reason was not specified anywhere obvious. Mods have been given explicit instructions not to touch that profile. While this particular incident may be limited to SO, the implications of this affect the entire network

@Trish When a user is deleted, their username is changed to their user ID on all their posts. SE considers this as removing one's attribution, as when a user requests deletion of their profile, they are also at the same time requesting their attribution be removed from all posts.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump Thanks for the clarification. However, the main question asked in this post isn't "can profile's names be changed in general etc etc.", it's "was there a reason for deleting the desired name for attribution on this account" - that's still a site-specific question since the user doesn't have profiles on any network site other than SO.

@Trish that's not how it works. You're not attributed, under the terms of the license, because you have a profile on a site.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog this is on topic because it involves SE, Inc. and site-wide policies like the terms in which SE, Inc. will strip attribution -- unless you can point to there being site-specific reasons that are only applicable to StackOverflow.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog just to be clear that's not the main question the main question is in the title "Removing attribution because someone was charged but not convicted with a crime?"

This shouldn't be closed. User name changes driven by mods or staff and compliance with the CC license terms has been an open question for a while. It extends well beyond cases where someone has been charged with a crime.

I had it bookmarked. (has nothing to do with the question). You can see the old profile here: https://web.archive.org/web/20241209234248/https://stackoverflow.com/users/4616250/luigi-mangione

@Jeremy From the CC BY-SA license's POV, it doesn't matter if the username is their real name. Authors are explicitly permitted to use a pseudonym. All that matters is that it's the attribution that was provided at the time the license was created. There are no provisions within the CC BY-SA license for changing attribution, only removing it completely, upon the request of the author.

This situation has a very direct precedent: "Frosty" (Ross Ulbricht) is still attributed under his chosen pseudonym and gets to keep the 500 not-very-organic upvotes on the question he asked in furtherance of the crime for which he was sentenced to life in prison and fined hundreds of millions of dollars.

Is the user in question really the same person who has been charged with murder, or just someone with the same name?

@Jeremy Maybe the difference is that there's nothing that publicly links the pseudonym "frosty" with the convicted criminal. But in this case the account name is identical to that of the alleged criminal.

@Barmar It's him. Since 2015 his avatar on Stack Exchange was the same as Luigi's on LinkedIn. Unless someone decided to impersonate him ten years ago, it's the same person.

Does attribution have to be a specific textual name, or is it sufficient for it to be a link to a profile that represents the author? If the latter, what they did didn't actually remove attribution.

@Barmar Attribution is about giving credit to the creator. Not about linking to a profile. I am not a profile; I am a person. I am the thing that gets attributed. I created the content, a profile did not create the content.

@Barmar The current Creative Commons licenses say explicitly that "If supplied, you must provide the name of the creator and attribution parties". It doesn't always need to be supplied in-line, you can sometimes get away with  provide a link which itself provides the name, but if a name was provided you do need to provide a way to find that name, at minimum. There may be additional requirements depending depending on how the content was initially distributed.

I wonder if there's something in the TOS that authorizes SE to forcibly change usernames, which may take precedence over the general CC-BY-SA license.

@Barmar I'm not aware of anything. I've previously pointed out this issue to SE, and even proposed some possible wording that would allow SE/mods to make strictly limited changes to usernames, but there's nothing I'm aware of there now, and I have looked. On the other hand, it's possible I missed something.

Note: there are possible legitimate reasons why SE might change a username. Two easy examples off the top of my head are A) the user requested it in some verified manner; B) it was legally required (e.g., ordered by a court).

IMO, the main problem with this question, as written, is that it assumes the reason why the changed were made (and, at the time, assumed who made the changes), and then makes accusations based on that assumed reason. It would be a much better question if it just stuck to the underlying issue of "Does SE have the right to change a user's username", and/or the related, general, questions, rather than focusing so hard on a single instance or a single assumed reason for making such change.

@Makyen I would also assume that usernames that are racist, offensive, attack others, pretend to be someone else, or other such things are legitimate reasons to forceable change a username. Given that a user can change the name that they use to link all of their content at will (with some time gating limitations) makes me think that as long as the content is still attributed to the creator changing the name isn't always a bad thing.

If you contribute and your chosen psuedonym is a slur, the company doesn't have the option of continuing to distribute the content but not including the slur. That's violating the law/license/contract. Including the slur is the licensing requirement, and they must comply if they wish to distribute the content. (This doesn't apply if you change your name to a slur after the contented is posted, and they change it back. They're allowed to do that, since you initially licensed it with the non-slur name specified.) The solution is deleting the posts so there’s no longer any license to worry about.

@Jeremy A normal SE deletion isn't sufficient, as even "deleted" posts are still distributed (e.g., can be seen by some users and moderators). The posts would actually need to be removed, as in not distributed to anyone outside of company staff. The alternative is to use the second license. But, if they use the second license, then they can't also say that the post has a CC BY-SA license. As far as I'm aware, there's no provision for doing that within the SE site software, as it currently exists.

@JoeW Changing the username in those circumstances isn't a bad thing, but it's still not legitimate under the CC BY-SA license, as Jeremy described. For the site to work reasonably, there are times when moderators or staff need to be able to change a users username, as you've identified. The problem is that the current site legal documents don't provide a framework where mods or staff changing the user's username doesn't violate the CC BY-SA license, as far as I'm aware.

@Makyen This seems to be a special case given everything that is happening around the internet regarding the person in question. If anything this is a preemptive change to prevent possible issues due to the name in question and could easily be reverted later once things die down.

@JoeW Does the license or overriding law allow them to alter attributions for the sake of ease during weird times? I don't think anyone's arguing about the sense of what's been done, it's the legality and implications for everyone else that's at issue.

@Mayken if SE has violated the license granted to it by a contributor by removing attribution, then the contributor can sue to enforce the license and require SE to restore attribution, and probably to enjoin SE from removing attribution in the future.  I suspect that in this case the user has other priorities.

@EvanCarroll then they can pursue arbitration.  The point is that there is a mechanism for user4616250 to vindicate his rights.  We the user community have no standing to do so.  We do have a general interest in Stack Exchange's behavior because we have also licensed our content to them, of course.

@Trish the right of attribution includes a right to specify the form of that attribution, including to a pseudonym of your choosing (presumably not without limit, as you can't claim a right to have your content attributed to a famous author, for example).  I have a right to demand that my content be attributed to "phoog" and not to "user156890" nor my real name, just as you have a right for yours to be attributed to "Trish" rather than to any other name.

@Jeremy I doubt the 500 upvotes were because people supported what he did. More likely it’s just an effect of it was indeed a good question and it got tons of views hence tons of upvotes

Yes, this seems silly. If people want to waste their reputation and time on increasing the Internet point counter of presumably inactive accounts, that is up to them. In a decade, no one will even remember why people were doing it, assuming this site still exists—they will be too busy watching Skibidi Toilet Part X by Michael Bay or something. It's inconsequential one way or another. But SE violating the terms of its license is clearly something that is bad for everyone here, and again, not even beneficial to them because of the triviality of the issue (Streisand effect?)

@zibadawatimmy If it is going to cause issues for the site and the question is to delete the content or change the name I would argue that changing the name is the better course as that can be reverted more easily at a later date.

@JanDoggen I am guessing that the action took place because of what others would likely do in reaction to that name based on how it is spreading on the internet rather then actions taken by that person.

The much more likely reason for changing the username was to prevent increased voting fraud. Given that there was more than 1,600 reputation very recently reversed for voting fraud on the affected user's account, it's clear that the account was actually being targeted by one or more users to dump reputation to this user, including three 500 reputation bounties and a substantial number of upvotes. While I have no actual knowledge of why the username was changed, it's much more likely that it was changed to protect from further abuse, rather than the reason assumed in this question.

You are making a large assumption with your leap to accuse them of doing this because of the crimes that got committed instead of other reasons such as all the publicity that the name is causing and what people are doing. This is hardly the first time that they have force changed a user name and it won't be the last. I am also sure you can find other users on the network that are linked to crimes that don't have their names changed.


I know one such user has had his right of attribution stripped.

There is no reason to believe that the situation you are asking about involves the user's rights having been stripped.  If the company changed the name on that user's account then it is possible that that constitutes a violation of that user's copyrights in their contributions, but that's not the same thing as stripping rights.  The Stack Exchange network is not empowered to strip rights granted to its users by law, and to the best of my knowledge, it has not claimed otherwise.


Given that the company removed the name from this account, does Stack Exchange claim that they can strip attribution at any time when a person is charged, and not even convicted, of a crime?

As far as I am aware, SE has not made any public comment about the particular case in question.  What remains, then, is the general terms of service.  Those terms incorporate some separate documents by reference, especially the acceptable use policy.  The primary terms governing "subscriber content" are:

You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any
and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images,
illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations,
and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the
public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually
and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide,
royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons
licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the
perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process,
copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such
Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been
contributed and subsequently removed by you as reasonably necessary
to, for example (without limitation):

Provide, maintain, and update the public Network
Process lawful requests from law enforcement agencies and government agencies
Prevent and address security incidents and data security features, support features, and to provide technical assistance as it may be
required
Aggregate data to provide product optimization


It's unclear to me whether the second part grants more rights to Stack Overflow than CC BY-SA 4.0 would do alone, but even if it does, I do not read it to override the CC attribution requirements.
The acceptable use policy is peripherally relevant as well. It describes several kinds of network usage that are prohibited, and it sets out that

If you are found to be in violation of any of the below sections, your access to the Network may be restricted or terminated without notice, and your content may be removed at our discretion.

That is, users agree that SO may remove their content if it constitutes an unacceptable use of the site.  This seems to be the only recourse SO reserves for responding to unacceptable use, and exercising it would not violate SO's CC license to the affected content.
Overall, then, Stack Exchange does not appear to have made any explicit claim that there are any circumstances in which they are freed from the CC BY-SA attribution requirements subject to which they use "subscriber content".  That they performed actions that might put them in breach of some of those licenses should not be taken as a claim to the contrary, and probably does not indicate that they think otherwise even privately.  Indeed, if they acted of their own accord in this case, then my first guess would be that they didn't even consider the content licensing angle before doing so.

"It's unclear to me whether the second part grants more rights to Stack Overflow than CC BY-SA 4.0 would do alone, but even if it does, I do not read it to override the CC attribution requirements." Can you elaborate on why you read the second license as not overriding attribution requirements?

As mentioned in the text you quoted, it includes distribution, copying and commercially exploiting as well as it's mentioned next to the CC license and not as a part of it.

@dan1st, I stopped in this answer with "I do not read it to" because IANAL.  However, if there were a lawsuit over this licensing, I anticipate that the rights holder would argue that inasmuch as reading the additional permissions granted as a separate and independent license, such that it moots the CC licensing, is unnatural (why then mention CC at all?) and inconsistent with a reasonable person's expectation of what the terms mean.  A valid contract requires a meeting of the minds about the terms, so if the terms of service are effective at all then the CC's obligations bind SO.

With that argument, why would the second license be necessary at all?

@dan1st, as this answer already expresses, I'm not sure the enumerated permissions are necessary, functionally. I doubt that they give SO any rights that CC BY-SA alone would not grant, and I'm inclined to think that the extra terms are there for CYA purposes, because contract lawyers are like that.  SO wants to be clear that those specific capabilities are allowed to it, and I suspect that they especially want to nail down the "even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you" part.

Why post this answer on a question that is explicitly asking for a response from SE, and not for individual users to weigh-in on what they feel the legal situation is? This is not a [tag:discussion] question. This is a [tag:support] question that is primarily asking for what is in the mind of people at Stack Exchange, the company. If you felt you had to discuss this, then you should have created a new, general question, that asks for a [tag:discussion] about the issue. If the question was asking for opinions, then it would have already been answered by several people.

Admittedly, you did do a decent job of trying to address what is in the existing site legal documents (based on my recollections). However, that's really not what was being asked for here, although it's a lot closer to what was being asked than the other non-deleted answer.

The TOS license does not change the CC-BY-SA license. SE can decide which license to use, but for any distribution for which they choose CC-BY-SA that’s what applies. Notably as written in the footer here and other stack pages "user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA".


...does Stack Exchange claim that they can strip attribution at any time when a person is charged, and not even convicted, of a crime?

Because no other answer yet says so, I will answer simply with: Yes it seems so.
Even more to the point, I think that Stack Exchange thinks they can change the user name of any user at any point regardless of if the user is charged or convicted by a crime or not.
My evidence: it's not the first time a user's name is forcibly changed. See for example here but I also remember incidences during Monica gate in 2019 and general discussions about the limits of user names. Typically moderators would force the rename of a user account but they work on behalf of the company there anyway.
Whether that is an overreach or even illegal, I don't know, I'm not a lawyer. But I think that some flexibility must be allowed for cases like someone wanting to call himself "kill xxx" for example. It's fine for me if the company uses discretion there.
Please also note that the company doesn't really have interest in policing user names, so even if they could theoretically change all user names (and that would not be a violation of any license contract), they very likely won't do so and only under special circumstances like here.
Finally, for the data dumps that might be different. You can refer to an old data dump and of course refer to the previous user name when building your own site. You may even have to according to the attribution clauses of the Creative Commons licenses used. Just because the company changed a user name after content has been created doesn't mean it becomes legal if others do that too.

Practically a good example here would be spammers. We don't have a good way to deal with them cross network, sometimes they're renamed to speed up handling them if they spam again... they can change their usernames back and don't. That said, as a moderator, I'd be mod messaging a user I renamed for 'operational' reasons like what's happened here and making sure people were informed of what was happening.  In this case, the comments indicate there was some inauthentic voting, and considering its the holidays, it might be a quick fix to mitigate that.

Your evidence is pretty thin considering that instance was due to a moderator on Code Review changing their username (imo, in bad taste). The example in question is evidence enough.

Licensing is a matter of civil, not criminal law. Until a person who has experienced such a user-name change chooses to complain, and perhaps file suit, no one can state, definitively, whether the action of SE was consistent with the requirements of the license or not. If there was a large volume of case law from analogous events, then someone could reasonably offer an analysis. It is my belief that the case law in this situation is not nearly thick enough to arrive at that point.
It is also very unlikely that SE would choose to reveal their precise legal reasoning in deciding to make the change. They might have any number of legal analyses of how this action, which for all we know is intended to be temporary, is legally justified. Or, for that matter, they might have made a business decision that the advantages of removing the content from the Google results on the man outweigh the legal risks entailed in losing the argument if he ever chooses to challenge them.
All of this is, indeed, speculation. The point of the speculation is to offer the answer that there is likely no answer to be had. Certainly no one outside of SE can accurately state their reasoning, and they have good reasons not to state it.

This actually seems like a really good point given the particular case.

This doesn't answer the question. The question explicitly asks for an answer from SE on this specific instance and specifically in response to the Evan's assumption that the username was changed due to the user being accused of a crime. This question is not asking for discussion on what we independently feel the legal analysis is of the situation. If it was, it would have already been answered by multiple people. For that, Evan asked a different question on [law.se]: "Do you lose the right of attribution if you're charged with a crime?"

Demanding an answer from SE is a long-established way to hear nothing. I offer this answer in the spirit that an explanation of why is of some value to the OP. If the necessary voters disagree, they will delete, and I will not suffer.

We've already had two speculative non-answers deleted, and this is just more of the same. Instead of insisting that other people manage your content appropriately, please delete the post yourself.

This is a very good answer to the (in comments to the question proposed) rephrasing towards "Why was Luigi Mangione's account renamed?", but this is not an answer to the actual question: is it permitted to rename an account based on alleged criminal activities of the person? Luigi Mangione is an example, but not the sole focus of the question that is asked. Given that another user is tomorrow found guilty of a crime, is it inevitably allowed that they lose their attribution if SE wants it to be lost? That is the question.

@Nij I am not exactly wet behind the ears here. I think that under the particular circumstances that this is a valid answer, but the only way to tell for sure is to see if N of my peers vote to delete it. If there were a meta.meta.stackexchange.com i could ask a question :-)

@Makyen: Where does the question explicitly ask for a response from SE? It merely asks "Does Stack Exchange claim...", and thus people who don't speak for SE may legitimately answer. Readers may regard such responses as non-authoritative, but as Rosinante notes, that's the best you'll get. Otherwise, the question is essentially rhetorical.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The question states "does Stack Exchange claim [...]".
